# Change the limit from CakePHP 3 Paginator by click in link inside an <option>

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using the CakePHP 3.0 to paginate some content, but I can't enconter a way to change the limit (user on browser choose the limit of content displayed on screen) using `Paginator` built-in method (like sort built-in), to do this I use javascript to change limit in URL.

**Qustion:** Exist any way to do this in cakephp style ?

**Controller action that uses paginate**

```
public $helpers = [
    'Paginator' => ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']
];

public function search()
{
    if($this->request->is('get'))
    {
        $search = $this->request->query['search'];
        @$limit = $this->request->query['limit'] ?: 3;

        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => ['product_name LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%'],
            'limit' => $limit,
            'contain' => ['Medias' => function($q){
                return $q->select(['path', 'product_id'])
                    ->where(['media_type_id' => 3]);
            }]
        ];

        $products = $this->paginate($this->Products);
     }
}
```

**Select with pagination limits:**

```
<select name="products-view" class="form-control products-view inline-pagination-menu" id="products-view">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript responsible to change `limit` in URL**

```
$('#products-view').change(function(){
    changeLimitPagination(this);
});

function changeLimitPagination(option){
    location.search = $.query.set('limit', option.value).toString();
}
```

Comment: First of all, please clarify what exactly you are referring to with "_limit_"! The `limit` option of the paginator component? Also please explain what exactly should happen when the limit is being changed (how/should it affect the currently selected page, etc).

Comment: @ndm I clarify in my question